# t-test with drift in reference distribution

Tags: t-test, quality-control

I wonder whether I am behaving correctly with my [Student t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) exercise.

I am continuously testing a small data sample of metal-detector antenna readings against a calibration sample distribution.

I am experiencing slow **drifts** in the distribution of my data (due to several factors like temperature raise, or soil composition changes, etc.), and I want to be able to automatically follow the drift in order to keep the t-test reliable in the long run.

My current idea is to adjust the *mean* of the calibration sample at each iteration, given some constraints:

```
WHILE(true) {
    ... t-test calculations...
    IF (p-value < P_LIMIT) {
        E(X_cal) += (DRIFT_WEIGHT * (E(X_test)-E(X_cal))
    }
}
```

Hence, only when I have a certain confidence on the null-hypothesis, then I adjust the calibration in the direction of the currently computed mean, weighting properly.

In this situation, in case of a slow drift, the calibration mean would be pushed towards the current mean iteration after iteration until it calibrates.

**QUESTION**: I wonder if this is making some sense, or whether I am violating important corner-stone rules in statistical distribution comparisons.

Comment: What does your actual raw data look like? What are you testing?

Comment: Metal-detector antenna values, imagine a normal distribution (verified) with a mean value around 500.000 and a variance at rest of around a few hundreds.

Comment: And then something counts as a detection? So you want to detect outliers somehow?

Comment: I want to detect differences between the calibration and test sample *means*: `H0 = abs(mu1-mu2)>threshold`. That would mean that there is a relevant presence of metal and hence a positive shall be triggered.

Comment: Maybe you should make a control chart and look into methods from quality control? One goal of such methods is to detect drifts in processes.

Comment: Thank you @kjetilbhalvorsen. I'm afraid I might have not clearly understood what you mean: any useful link so that I can dig in a little more?

Comment: You could start with this:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15364/understanding-statistical-control-charts   And [here is a longer list](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=control+chart++answers%3A1+score%3A1)